# How to stop default select event action in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded a JQuery plug-in, but there are some troubles with that. I want to select multi-row in a table by  pressing down the shift key and click a table row, but when I selected some browser, its default style is added to the selected text. I don't have enough reputation to post a picture. 
[Please click here to see the picture](http://www.dewen.org/q/13831/jquery/javascript%E9%98%BB%E6%AD%A2%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8%E9%80%89%E4%B8%AD%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6%E7%9A%84%E9%BB%98%E8%AE%A4%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C).

how can I wipe out those style?

Comment: Just use an alternative solution to select multiple row, use `checkbox`

Comment: i just want to select rows likes in windows from.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the user selection in css -

```
table{
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}
```

Comment: This version is more complete, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: @pXL yes!Its function well!Thank you!

Comment: oh!but it can not function in ie8 and firefox!

Answer (score 0):

finally,I get a way to solve this problem,by preventing text be selected.code as follows

```
if (typeof document.onselectstart!="undefined")
    document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false");
else{
    document.onmousedown=false;
    document.onmouseup=true;
}
```

But, I have never been able to select the text.